# Is it possible to make linked object local when it is invisible (Restrict viewport visibility is turned off)?

Tags: objects, linked-data, visibility

It seems if I have a linked object and it is invisible (Restrict viewport visibility is turned off in the original .blend file) there is no way to make it local, because *make local* (as other commands as well) only works if the object is visible.

So is there a workaround or python scirpt or something to solve this?

[image]